# WP element placement on responsive site

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a premium theme site in dev here

http://brettcolephotography.com/sites/sra/

based on this theme

http://themes.danyduchaine.com/mission/

The theme comes with an odd logo placement, you can see, the little black circle. Client needed it to be in the left of the nav. I've implemented this solution

1. Moved the nav over to the right with margin-left to make room. This change behaves well.
2. Added a nested div structure for the logo, using css pointer-event to account for the div layering and the click-through issues that arise with my approach

html

```
<div id="bc-masthead">
<div id="bc-logo">
<div id="bc-logo-img"><a href="http://brettcolephotography.com/sites/sra/"><img src="http://brettcolephotography.com/sra.png"   /></a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#bc-masthead {position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 40px; width: 100%; pointer-events:none; z-index: 9999999 !important;}
#bc-logo {max-width: 930px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: left; position: relative; top: 7px; pointer-events:none;}
#bc-logo-img {width: 205px; pointer-events: auto;}
```

Overall it gets pretty far to the goal. The issues that arise are:

1. IE comptability with the pointer-event. I frankly don't understand any of the javascript alternatives I've seen for this part, but am not sure if there's another alternative or if I am facing compatibility issues. I tried it in IE10 and it seemed fine.
2. At mobile size the white mobile nav box that appears (responsive theme) is under the logo and I can't seem to change that no matter what I try.

I am open to different approaches altogether or insights on how to make what I've done so far work 100%. Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks Josh, I'll give it a try here. I've seen a lot more complicated problems solved here. I would like to learn from it.

Comment: You're using fixed positioning that's why the logo overlaps the menu at smaller sizes.  It looks like you're modifying the theme's template files, which could get overwritten if the theme ever has any updates and you update it to the new version.  But this might not be an issue if you're doing this outside of the default theme files, like creating your own uniquely named template file.  Since you're willing to modify the HTML, why not find the snippet that generates the `.sliderLogo` DIV and its contents and place it right before the `.mainNav` DIV?